# Taking a value out of a loop?

Tags: java, loops, math

This is a program to find out what age someone would have to be for their age to be the square root of the year. How do I take an age and the associating year out of this loop so that I can print it?

```
package squareAges;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class SquareAges {

    public static final int MIN_YEAR = 1893;
    public static final int MAX_YEAR = 2139;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int age = 0; age <= 123; age++) {
            System.out.println(age + "= " + age * age + " ");

            if (MIN_YEAR <= (age * age) && (age * age) <= MAX_YEAR) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is possible that someone  alive   today "
                        + "has, is, or will be     alive in a year that is the square of their age.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: declare int sqrtAge = 0 outside the for loop and then assign sqrtAge = age * age; inside it

Comment: I'm looking to take a particular value out of the loop, (eg) age 45 = year 2025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print only *particular* values satisfying your above condition , you can use an **if** inside the loop, The code can be like:

```
int age, year;
for (year = 1893; year <= 2139; year++) {
    for (age = 0; age <= 123; age++) {
        System.out.println(age + "= " + age * age + " ");

        if (MIN_YEAR <= (age * age) && (age * age) <= MAX_YEAR) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is possible that someone  alive   today "
                    + "has, is, or will be     alive in a year that is the square of their age.");

            if (age * age == year) {
                System.out.println("Age is:" + age + "Year is:" + year);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm looking to take a particular value out of the loop, (eg) age 45 = year 2025

Comment: Edited my answer as per your comment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Introduce local variable outside the loop.
2. Assign it in `if` statement.
3. Do `break` in `if` statement.
4. Use local variable after loop.

Comment: I'm looking to take a particular value out of the loop, (eg) age 45 = year 2025